# Download specific files from .txt url using Python

Tags: python, url, download

How to download specific files from .txt url?

I have a url `https://.storage.public.eu/opendata/files/open_data_files_access.txt` (not real) with multiple files (here are just a few, in reality there are around 5k files) that can be downloaded separately, however I would need to download only specific files, and do this with Python.

For instance, I have a list with folder name and list of file name. How do I download only those file that are on the list? Let's say the list is:

`files = ['folder1_file_1.jpg', 'folder1_file_2.jpg', 'folder1_file_3.jpg', 'folder1_file_4.jpg', 'folder1_file_10.jpg', 'folder2_file_2.jpg', 'folder2_file_3.jpg', 'folder3_file_1.jpg', 'folder3_file_3.jpg', 'folder3_file_4.jpg']`

How to download only these in the list and save in specified directory?

[image]

I assume that the answer is somewhere here, but no work for me:

```
uurl = 'https://.storage.public.eu/opendata/files/open_data_files_access.txt'

from requests import get  # to make GET request

def download(url, file_name):
    # open in binary mode
    with open(file_name, "wb") as file:
        # get request
        response = get(url)
        # write to file
        file.write(response.content)

file_name' = ['folder1_file_1.jpg', 'folder1_file_2.jpg', 'folder1_file_3.jpg', 'folder1_file_4.jpg', 'folder1_file_10.jpg', 'folder2_file_2.jpg', 'folder2_file_3.jpg', 'folder3_file_1.jpg', 'folder3_file_3.jpg', 'folder3_file_4.jpg']

download(uurl, file_name)
```

Comment: 1. What doesnt work? 2. Your code has syntax errors.

Comment: Its TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list for file_name, but the problem is I only have file names not path.

Comment: You're passing a list of file names to `open`, while it expects only one file. You should loop through the file_name list and call download for each item. `[download(uurl, fname) for fname in file_name]`